# R - how do we use grepl or str_detect againts vector list? c()

Tags: r

How do we use grepl function against lists in a vector?

So what I`m trying to do is...

```
Campaign                 Vendor         
yy                        yyxxx       
yxzrr                     yxz         
xxx3                      yz          
xxx4                      xxx4_zh     
xxx5                      xxx5_xj_78
```

... 100,000 more rows

Given this dataframe, I would like to find which "Vendor" are matching 
against "Campaign". But since there are no exact match, I was thinking to use
`grepl` or `grep` or `str_detect` function to map them
and if they match, I would like to insert a new row with the Campaign in a new column

Is there way to efficiently automate this mapping process?

I tried using, something like below...

But wasn`t working properly

```
Campaign_list <- unique(Campaign)

ifelse(grepl(c(Campaign_list), DCM$Campaigns), "Y", "N")
```

Comment: So what's the desired output here?

Comment: So the desired output will be.. first row of Vendor column = "yy" second row of Vendor column = "yxz" etc.. basically if the strings of Campaign is included in "Vendor" column, make another column with that Campaign row

Answer (score 0):

Function Vectorize will help:

```
DCM <- read.table(text = c('
  Campaign                 Vendor         
  yy                        yyxxx       
  yxzrr                     yxz         
  xxx3                      yz          
  xxx4                      xxx4_zh     
  xxx5                      xxx5_xj_78'
  ), header = TRUE )

vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl)

# rows in Vendor that match with Campaign:
vgrepl(DCM$Vendor, DCM$Campaign)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# rows in Campaign that match with Vendor:
vgrepl(DCM$Campaign, DCM$Vendor)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# Combining both:
ifelse(apply(cbind(vgrepl(DCM$Vendor, DCM$Campaign), vgrepl(DCM$Campaign, DCM$Vendor)), 1, any), 'Y', 'N')
[1] "Y" "Y" "N" "Y" "Y"
```

Comment: But shouldn`t the output be "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y" ? because all the lists there under Campaign have strings in vendor, except third one

Comment: You can invert the comparison, but note that the string "yxzrr" is not present in "yxz". So what you need is to find what strings in Vendor are present in Campaign and also the ones in Campaign that are presented in Vendor. I updated the answer. I suggest that you update the question with your desired output, that will help users to provide other solutions.

Comment: Thank you Carlos!! This worked, is there way to vote for your comment?

Comment: No need to thank, OS users are here to help each other. If the answer helped, vote on the answer. If you also want to vote for the comment, there's an up arrow on the side of it.